# Load local .obj model threejs + vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

I'm having trouble importing a 3d .obj model in my vue cli project.

When I use a model from a web url it works just fine but whenever I try to load a local model it doesn't appear and I get the following error [image: console error]

I read online that this happens when the path to the file is incorrect but I tried many possible paths and it still didn't work. This post https://github.com/dwqdaiwenqi/react-3d-viewer/issues/6 suggested to move the file to the public folder but it didn't solve anything for me.

Here's my Loader, the commented code is the loader that uses an url and this one works

```
// ERROR LOADER
              const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
          objLoader.load('../../public/piano_test.obj', (root) => {
            console.log(root);
            scene.add(root);
          });
    
    // WORKING LOADER
          // const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
          // objLoader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/windmill/windmill.obj', (root) => {
          //   console.log(root);
          //   scene.add(root);
          // })
```

And this is my folder, right now I'm working in HelloWorld.vue for testing purpose [image: folder]

I also tried to move piano_test.obj in the assets folder using the path './assets/piano_test.obj' and it didn't work either.

Comment: Public objects should not be accessed through relative paths, but rather through absolute paths. `/piano_test.obj` should be all you need for the URL.

Comment: That did the trick thank you